# Selecting cells with certain colour (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find solution for my VBA project which requires to select and copy data from cells which are colored with certain colour (I know that there is no need to select range before copy, but at this point I just check how selecting range input works). I tried one solution provided by dollarexcel.com (with some modifications), but when I exceed certain range I get error '1004' - Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed. With smaller ranges it works fine.

Here is code, I changed it to find colored cells in fixed range, not in current selection (but it also generated same error if manually selected range was too big). Error highlists third line from the bottom. I would appreciate any help with this issue.

```vb
Sub select_cells_with_colour()

Dim selected_Range As Range
Set selected_Range = Range("H20:I33")
mystr = ""
    For Each cellitem In selected_Range
         If cellitem.Interior.ColorIndex = 37 Then
            mystr = mystr & cellitem.Address & ","
         End If
    Next
    If mystr = "" Then
        MsgBox "No colored cell found"
    Else
        Range(Left(mystr, Len(mystr) - Len(","))).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Likely `myStr` is too long (there's a 255-character limit for addresses passed to `Range`). Use `Union` instead.

Comment: I don't get it: people regularly colour cells, generally following a condition which suits for them. On that idea Microsoft has created the conditional formatting feature. It means that coloured cells generally obey a condition. ... but when people want to have a list of that information, instead of looking for the condition, they look for the colour :-) Pardon me this piece of sarcasm but tell me: what is the reason you are looking for those coloured cells? And are you aware that conditionally formatted cells are not coloured in the same way as normally coloured cells?

Comment: @Dominique its not my choice unfortunately. I'm working with some kind of report for mother company (deliveried by them) and cells which are supossed to be filled with data from our side are colored. There is no general pattern in coloring these cells becaue there are several sheets and tables with different sizes and purpose. So I think there is no need for sarcasm here :) And yes, I'm aware that conditional formatting and just colored cells use different properties/methods.

Comment: @BigBen thank you, didn't know about exact limits for addresses passed to Range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Select Cells With the Same Color Index

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SelectCellsWithColorIndex()

    Const rgAddress As String = "H20:I33"
    Const cIndex As Long = 37
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(rgAddress)
    
    Dim crg As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    For Each cell In rg.Cells
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = cIndex Then
            If crg Is Nothing Then
                Set crg = cell
            Else
                Set crg = Union(crg, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    
    If crg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No colored cells found.", vbExclamation
    Else
        crg.Select
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Definetly storing cell addresses in some kind of variable matrix wasn't good idea at all. I have never used Union function before so also kudos to you for this introduction.